# Troubles with the Nucleon Bound Energies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, nuclear-physics

I was reading my quantum mechanics text and I have a doubt. I have the energy levels well defined for the finite square well and the author suddenly compares (I believe) those levels with the levels of the nucleon with the following phrase: "is the spacing between levels on the order of MeV for a nucleon bound in a several-fm well?". So I have some troubles understanding the meaning of that particular pharse.

Thanks.

Comment: Which quantum mechanics text are you reading?

Comment: You are suppose to treat whatever potential the author has just been discussing as a model for the binding of a nucleon in a nucleus and see if the results are sane (real nucleons *are* typically bound to real nuclei at the few MeV level). Sane results suggest the model in question has at least a vague resemblance to reality, insane results show that the model diverges substantially from reality. This kind of thing is a basic skill for reading textbooks and you should try to cultivate it even where the author does not suggest it.

Comment: Hi @Qmechanic , it is the book "Computational Physics Problem Solving with computers; R. H. Landau and M. J. Paez, John Wiley & Sons"